# .net DirectX Flip or Mirror a IGraphBuilder (webcam)

Tags: directx, directshow.net

Been going round in circles, new to directx and using directshow in c#  I need to flip and mirror a webcam stream, could anyone provide pointers on how to do this from a graphBuilder.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the webcam stream working? Are you displaying frames? What is the current state of the project, and can we see the code you have created to build the graph?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a full-screen quad to flip the image by changing the texture coordinates in DirectX. I.e. define 4 points with UV coordinates from 1.0 to 0.0 (instead of 0.0 to 1.0) to flip the image. Alternatively you can use dotNet to do it using Image.RotateFlip() with the appropriate param from System.Drawing.RotateFlipType